# Is there a way to cancel requestAnimationFrame without a global variable?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, requestanimationframe, cancelanimationframe

I'm trying to cancel a `requestAnimationFrame` loop, but I can't do it because each time `requestAnimationFrame` is called, a new timer ID is returned, but I only have access to the return value of the first call to `requestAnimationFrame`.
Specifically, my code is like this, which I don't think is entirely uncommon:

```
function animate(elem) {

  var step = function (timestamp) {

    //Do some stuff here.
    if (progressedTime < totalTime) {
      return requestAnimationFrame(step); //This return value seems useless.
    }

  };

  return requestAnimationFrame(step);

}

//Elsewhere in the code, not in the global namespace.
var timerId = animate(elem);

//A second or two later, before the animation is over.
cancelAnimationFrame(timerId); //Doesn't work!
```

Because all subsequent calls to `requestAnimationFrame` are within the `step` function, I don't have access to the returned timer ID in the event that I want to call `cancelAnimationFrame`.

Looking at the way [Mozilla (and apparently others do it)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame), it looks like they declare a global variable in their code (`myReq` in the Mozilla code), and then assign the return value of each call to `requestAnimationFrame` to that variable so that it can be used any time for `cancelAnimationFrame`.

Is there any way to do this without declaring a global variable?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't need to be a global variable; it just needs to have scope such that both `animate` and `cancel` can access it. I.e. you can encapsulate it. For example, something like this:

```
var Animation = function(elem) {
  var timerID;
  var step = function() {
    // ...
    timerID = requestAnimationFrame(step);
  };
  return {
    start: function() {
      timerID = requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
    cancel: function() {
      cancelAnimationFrame(timerID);
    }
  };
})();

var animation = new Animation(elem);
animation.start();
animation.cancel();
timerID; // error, not global.
```

EDIT: You don't need to code it *every time* - that's why we are doing programming, after all, to abstract stuff that repeats so we don't need to do it ourselves. :)

```
var Animation = function(step) {
  var timerID;
  var innerStep = function(timestamp) {
    step(timestamp);
    timerID = requestAnimationFrame(innerStep);
  };
  return {
    start: function() {
      timerID = requestAnimationFrame(innerStep);
    }
    cancel: function() {
      cancelAnimationFrame(timerID);
    }
  };
})();
var animation1 = new Animation(function(timestamp) {
  // do something with elem1
});
var animation2 = new Animation(function(timestamp) {
  // do something with elem2
});
```

Comment: You are right in your solution, but what is annoying with it is that I then have to code out something similar every time I want to use `requestAnimationFrame`. Of course, realistically, I don't use `requestAnimationFrame` that often (maybe 2-3 places in my code), but still, if I have to code something like that out each time I use it, I'd rather just declare a global / properly encapsulated variable, and just know to use that variable for the timer ID in all cases. Not ideal, but I'm not going to add a bunch of code to work around the bad design of `requestAnimationFrame`. Any other ideas?